# How to do error-handling of JSON Parser Loop

Tags: python, json, parsing

I found some elegant code that builds a `list` by iterating through each element of another JSON list:

```
results = [
    (
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["winery"]["name"],
        t["vintage"]["year"],
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["id"],
        f'{t["vintage"]["wine"]["name"]} {t["vintage"]["year"]}',
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["statistics"]["ratings_average"],
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["statistics"]["ratings_count"],
        t["price"]["amount"],
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["region"]["name"],
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["name"], #<--------------issue here
        
    )
    for t in r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"]
]
```

The problem is that sometimes the JSON doesn't have a "name" element because the "style" is null (or None in JSON world). See the second-last line below for the JSON sample.

Is there a simple way to handle this error?

Error:

```
matches[23]["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["name"]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-94-59447d0d4859>", line 1, in <module>
    matches[23]["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["name"]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Perhaps something like:

```
iferror(t["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["name"], "DoesNotExist")
```

JSON:

```
{'id': 4026076,
 'name': 'Shiraz - Petit Verdot',
 'seo_name': 'shiraz-petit-verdot',
 'type_id': 1,
 'vintage_type': 0,
 'is_natural': False,
 'region': {'id': 685,
  'name': 'South Eastern Australia',
  'name_en': '',
  'seo_name': 'south-eastern',
  'country': {'code': 'au',
   'name': 'Australia',
   'native_name': 'Australia',
   'seo_name': 'australia',
   'sponsored': False,
   'currency': {'code': 'AUD',
    'name': 'Australian Dollars',
    'prefix': '$',
    'suffix': None},
   'regions_count': 120,
   'users_count': 867353,
   'wines_count': 108099,
   'wineries_count': 13375,
   'most_used_grapes': [{'id': 1,
     'name': 'Shiraz/Syrah',
     'seo_name': 'shiraz-syrah',
     'has_detailed_info': True,
     'wines_count': 536370},
    {'id': 2,
     'name': 'Cabernet Sauvignon',
     'seo_name': 'cabernet-sauvignon',
     'has_detailed_info': True,
     'wines_count': 780931},
    {'id': 5,
     'name': 'Chardonnay',
     'seo_name': 'chardonnay',
     'has_detailed_info': True,
     'wines_count': 586874}],
   'background_video': None},
  'class': {'typecast_map': {'background_image': {}, 'class': {}}},
  'background_image': {'location': '//images.vivino.com/regions/backgrounds/0iT8wuQXRWaAmEGpPjZckg.jpg',
   'variations': {'large': '//thumbs.vivino.com/region_backgrounds/0iT8wuQXRWaAmEGpPjZckg_1280x760.jpg',
    'medium': '//thumbs.vivino.com/region_backgrounds/0iT8wuQXRWaAmEGpPjZckg_600x356.jpg'}}},
 'winery': {'id': 74363,
  'name': 'Barramundi',
  'seo_name': 'barramundi',
  'status': 0,
  'background_image': None},
 'taste': {'structure': None,
  'flavor': [{'group': 'black_fruit', 'stats': {'count': 16, 'score': 2987}},
   {'group': 'oak', 'stats': {'count': 11, 'score': 1329}},
   {'group': 'red_fruit', 'stats': {'count': 10, 'score': 1413}},
   {'group': 'spices', 'stats': {'count': 6, 'score': 430}},
   {'group': 'non_oak', 'stats': {'count': 5, 'score': 126}},
   {'group': 'floral', 'stats': {'count': 3, 'score': 300}},
   {'group': 'earth', 'stats': {'count': 3, 'score': 249}},
   {'group': 'microbio', 'stats': {'count': 2, 'score': 66}},
   {'group': 'vegetal', 'stats': {'count': 1, 'score': 100}},
   {'group': 'dried_fruit', 'stats': {'count': 1, 'score': 100}}]},
 'statistics': {'status': 'Normal',
  'ratings_count': 1002,
  'ratings_average': 3.5,
  'labels_count': 11180,
  'vintages_count': 25},
 'style': None,
 'has_valid_ratings': True}
```

Comment: Add complete json. couldn't reproduce this issue

Comment: You'd have to check if the key exists, eg `t["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["name"] if 'name' in t["vintage"]["wine"]["style"] else None`. But that implies creating individual exceptions for items in the tuple. Alternatvely you could load it with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and export the dataframe to a list.